# PyCharm: highlighting of any matching selected text

Tags: python, pycharm

In the code below, when I select the variable `date_received`, PyCharm just highlights the matching variable. What I want is that the string `'date_received'` of the line one must also be selected.

How can I do this in PyCharm?

```
t2 = dataset3[['user_id', 'coupon_id', 'date_received']]
t2.date_received = t2.date_received.astype('str')
```

Comment: @abccd  I have updated it. Thanks!

Comment: You may use on page search (`Ctrl+F`) as suggested in one of the answers -- it will highlight that text anywhere on a page quite prominently.

Answer (score 0):

To search a particular string/variable throughout the file you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and type the string. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to replace a string/variable with a new string/variable

Answer (score 0):

As for now, I don't think the PyCharm can highlight selection within a string. However, if you refactor you code by renaming a variable, you can do the replacement also in strings. Here is an example:

[image]